# Unusual event occurred when upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, 18.10, 19.04

[image: Camera captured photo]

I used "**sudo do-release-update**" command and update and upgrade began.

Now I don't know what is going on. Pop-up information is displayed and the "Esc" button doesn't close that information. There is no "ok" option to close this information. What should I do?

I'm afraid if something has gone wrong. Do I reboot or shutdown or type "sudo do-release-update" again?

Main question: how do I close "**Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer**" information from the terminal without closing terminal and without what's going on in the updating process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Tab" button to navigate to "ok" button. Matter will resolve.